Product to fill hole in brick foundation

Old service entrance has started to fall apart and insects have moved it. The hole is plugged with concrete on the inside.Once they're removed, how best should I fill this?
The mortar around it is cracked so I'm planning to make the hole bigger by removing loose pieces and then fill with what? I have Quickrete Quick-Setting Cement, I think their FastSet Repair Mortar would be a closer color match. It will be a decent size hole, I don't believe there was a brick piece missing and am fine with a large patch if that doesn't affect it's strength.
There are a few cracks in the joints to the bottom left of the hole as well I could fill at the same time.
Open to other suggested products to use.
